# XML namespace prefix cannot be empty

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal objects into XML and I have a problem with the namespaces prefix (I don't want to have any prefix).

I'm using bindigs file to customize the generated classes. 
The generated package-info.java file contains the following:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.test.com", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.test.com", prefix = "")})
package com.test;
```

So, the prefix is set to "", but when the XML is generated, I have a generated prefix.
If I use another value for prefix (different than an empty string), the XML is generated with the right prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation does not guarantee that it will use the prefixes specified in the `@XmlSchema` annotation.  [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) will and so will recent versions of the [**JAXB RI**](http://jaxb.java.net/).

The JAXB RI offers a `NamespacePrefixMapper` extension which is now supported by MOXy to give more control over the prefixes used.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Comment: I've read about this option before but I've hoped it can be solved only with bindings.

Comment: @ovi2ut - Like I said EclipseLink MOXy and recent versions of the JAXB RI will use the prefixes specified in the `@XmlSchema` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest JAXB, you must set QUALIFIED to elementFormDefault field of XmlSchema annotation. Like this:

```
@XmlSchema (
    elementFormDefault= XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    ...)
```

Otherwise, JAXB will add an auto prefix (ns1, ns2, ...)